# Linux, C++, Waiting for an event using poll/select ( w/o blocking the executing thread )

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, linux-kernel

### Use-case

- Single threaded Application
- Non-blocking Async-IO using **[poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll)**
- A waitable object ( eg. a mutex ) with a timeout period

### Problem at hand

I don;t want to create a specialized thread to wait for a timeout, and thus, I want to use **[poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll)** to wait for a timeout on the waitable object in an ~Async~ fashion.

Is it possible to get notified for a mutex wait timeout using **[poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll)**?

### Main thread Pseudo code

- Existing logic

  1. wait for multiple FDs using **[poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll)**
  2. for each ~ready~ FD, process the IO
  3. goto #1
- *Desired* Logic

  1. wait for multiple FDs **and Mutexes** using **[poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll)**
  2. for each ~ready~ FD, process the IO
  3. For each timedout mutex process timeout ( eg. execute a registered callback )
  4. For each signaled mutex process wait completion
  5. goto #1

Comment: why not just set the timeout to zero?

Comment: and repeatedly call poll

Comment: I can do that, but then, to avoid killing the CPU, I either need to sleep() between poll calls or set a timeout, and, any of these will adversely affect the timer resolution/accuracy, an optimal solution is to have a timer part of the FDs passed to the poll call...

Comment: I believe I have misunderstood your question. Can you perhaps provide some pseudo code, which explains how your suboptimal program looks like and how you'd like it to actually behave?

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Did you consider using a pipe to self?

Comment: While a pipe to self is used to register new FDs it will not resolve the above mentioned use-case, I need the call to poll to wait for both, FDs IO Completions and Wait object, something that is, to a certain extent, similar to windows WaitforMultipleObjects ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687028%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't know most of the Linux / Unix / Posix system functions, but I don't think this is possible without extra threads, as poll is nothing you can wait on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pthread mutexes do not have a file handle.

Implement your own mutex on top of [eventfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html), then you can wait for it with `poll()`.

Comment: Can I get timeout notifications for it?

Comment: poll() has a timeout.

Comment: Yeah, this timeout though is for all of the waited FDs and not for a specific one.